# Mapbox Choropleth Maps in Python does not plot data

Tags: python, plotly

I have a sub.geojson that i imported as geopandas dataframe and has the following columns - "SSC_CODE", "SSC_NAME" (suburb name), "CONF_VALUE"(rating), "SQKM". It has polygons of all the suburbs
[image]

[image]

Now my dataset with restaurant details has "lng", "lat" etc columns and i added"geometry" column that has points which were generated using lat and lng values. Did a spatial join, got rid of a few columns, filtered the data so i have all restaurants with indian cuisine and now the df looks like -
[image]

I grouped by ssc_code and added count to the df so i can get heatmap.
[image]

Now i can use the df to get a heatmap of the suburbs with indian restaurants. My code -

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 8))

gdf.plot("SQKM", ax=ax, color='white', edgecolor = "black")
indian.plot(column='count', cmap='viridis', linewidth=0.5, ax=ax, legend=True, edgecolor='k', alpha=0.7, legend_kwds={'label': "Indian Restaurant Number"})
plt.show()
```

It works great but when i try to use plotly, I can't plot the suburbs/polygons anymore. My code-

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(indian, 
# i tried passing the jsonfile, sub, indian(since indian df is merged sub and original df) for geojson
                           geojson=sub.geometry, 
                           locations=indian.SSC_CODE, 
                           color="count",
                           hover_name = "subzone",
                           hover_data = ["count"],
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron", 
                           center = dict(lat= -33.85 , lon=151.2153)
                           )
fig.show()
```

But it does not work. I only get a map of the region since my plot is centered but that's it, does not plot the suburbs from the dataframe. I was following along these - https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/

Comment: Can you post this as sample data as there is no way to reproduce it with geopandas data pasted as an image? Is the 'ssc_code' a number or a string? If it is a number, convert it to a string and run again.